# How to implement Prim's algorithm using STL ?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, unordered-map

I am trying to implement a data structure which is a combination of both a heap and an unordered map. 
The heap will hold the graph node , containing the identifier and the cost.
I use the min_extract function to get the node to expand next in log(n) time. [ I am implementing the heap using std::vector and std::make_heap , pop_heap etc from algorithm ]

The unordered map holds the node , position in the vector mapping. The unordered map is used to support contains and update-node functions. But for me to do this, I need the mapping between the node and its position in the vector, otherwise I am forced to do a linear search for the item.

Even more worrying is the case, where I push or pop an item, and call the push_heap or pop_heap, this will shift around the node in the vector and the positions that I maintain in the map, will end up being wrong.

So how can I implement the functionality, where I can maintain a mapping between the node and its position.

```
    void push(T elem) // This will 0(n)... As the element has to be found
    {
        heapVec_.push_back(elem); // add tp vec

        std::push_heap<compar_> (heapVec_.begin() , heapVec_.end());
        // sort ? or just find in the vec ? 
        std::size_t pos = 0 ;

        // find position of the item in the vector
        std::find_if(heapVec_.begin() , heapVec_.end() , [&pos , &elem](const T& item)
                {

                    if(item == elem)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ++pos;
                    }
                });


        // add to map
        heapMap_.emplace_back(elem , pos); // how to keep track of the element where this object is added to ? 

    }
```

The data structure I am looking for has to support : 
find min     : O(lg n)
contains     : O(1)
update-node  : O(lg n)
insert       : O(lg n)

It will be trivial to implement if I roll out my own heap where when I do the bubble up or down, I update the positions of the node in the map. Before I do that I wanted to make sure that I couldn't do it in STL.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prims-algorithm-using-priority_queue-stl/

Answer (score 0):

If you put *edges* into your priority queue instead of nodes, then you don't need that update-node function, and everything gets a whole lot easier.

- Use some kind of set implementation to keep track of which vertices are in the tree.
- Use a priority queue to maintain an ordered queue of possible edges.

Then:

1. Add an initial vertex to the set, and add its edges to the priority queue
2. Remove the cheapest edge E from the priority queue.
3. If one of E's vertices V is not in the tree, then add E and V to the tree.  V goes in your set.  If V has any edges to nodes that aren't in the set, then add those edges to the priority queue.
4. Go back to step 2 until the queue is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to start from an empty heap and push vertices in it as we proceed. We may push the same vertex multiple times into the heap, but we still form the MST correctly (using a parent list) and the overall complexity still remains O( E * log(V) ). This way we do not have to implement the `decrease_key` function.

One can implement this using `priority_queue`.
I, however, implemented it using `push_heap` and `pop_heap` functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;
void addEdge(vector<vector <pair<int, int> > >&adj, int u, int v, int w) 
{ 
    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v, w)); 
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u, w)); 
}

int main(){
  vector<vector <pair<int, int> > >adj(9); // Taking a 9 node graph for testing.
  addEdge(adj, 0, 1, 4); 
  addEdge(adj, 0, 7, 8); 
  addEdge(adj, 1, 2, 8); 
  addEdge(adj, 1, 7, 11); 
  addEdge(adj, 2, 3, 7); 
  addEdge(adj, 2, 8, 2); 
  addEdge(adj, 2, 5, 4); 
  addEdge(adj, 3, 4, 9); 
  addEdge(adj, 3, 5, 14); 
  addEdge(adj, 4, 5, 10); 
  addEdge(adj, 5, 6, 2); 
  addEdge(adj, 6, 7, 1); 
  addEdge(adj, 6, 8, 6); 
  addEdge(adj, 7, 8, 7);

  vector<int> key(9, INT_MAX);
  vector<int> parent(9, -1);
  vector<bool> isInMST(9, false);

  key[0] = 0; // Source node is 0, its key value is also 0.
  vector<pair<int, int> > heap; // Vector named as heap.
  heap.push_back(make_pair(0, 0)); // No need to call make_heap as it has only 1 element.

  while(!heap.empty()){
    pair<int, int> temp = heap.front();
    pop_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), [ ] (pair<int, int> l, pair<int, int> r){
      return l.first > r.first;
    });
    heap.pop_back();
    int u = temp.second;
    isInMST[u] = true;
    for(int i=0; i<adj[u].size(); i++){
      int v = adj[u][i].first;
      int w = adj[u][i].second;
      if(!isInMST[v] && key[v] > w){
        key[v] = w;
        heap.push_back(make_pair(w, v));
        push_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end(), [ ] (pair<int, int> l, pair<int, int> r){
          return l.first > r.first;
        });
        parent[v] = u;
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) // Starting from 1, as 0 is source.
    cout << parent[i] << " - " << i << endl; // Print edges of MST using parent array.

  return 0;
}
```